# Color accuracy issues Macbook / PC

Tags: adobe-photoshop, image-editing, color-profile, color-spaces, calibration

I have a weird behavior between a PC and a Macbook (2016) regarding color accuracy.

The PC is connected to a BenQ SW271 monitor and the monitor is in sRGB mode

Both are calibrated using the X-Rite i1Display Pro in controlled environment.

I edit on the PC most of the time.

On the PC when I view an sRGB picture on chrome and capture one they are identical.

If I do the same on the Macbook, they are also identical. Night shift is of course off.

BUT

When I compare between the Mac and the PC, the picture is warmer on chrome and capture one on the Mac. +20 more saturated

So what could be the culprit here ?
How can I find out what monitor is giving me the right colors ?

Thanks

Comment: Is the screen really xalibrated or just profiled? What is your system conversion intent set to? Crome is not color managed. All bets are of.

Comment: I've had a BenQ monitor and found is woefully inferior where color accuracy was concerned... (You get what you pay for. They are inexpensive monitors.) I ended up giving it away it was so bad. That's not to say all BenQ monitors are that bad, merely my own experience has caused me to never invest in a BenQ monitor again.

Comment: Did you run the large swatch samples, 400+ on profiling? I've found it a lot better than the default 120(?) Also, check you got the same display type & cd/m2 etc. Also check your workflow if you're in Adobe etc, many people put their display profile in their workflow, which just breaks things.

Comment: @joojaa What if the diff ? I ran the calibration device and then applied the generated profile.

Chrome use sRGB color space

Comment: @Scott It's dedicated to photographers and cost over 1K$. It has been praised a lot so that would be really surprising. I think the issue is more on the Macbook

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes I went with the biggest option available.

I put the BenQ in sRGB mode and in my editing tool it's also in sRGB.
On the Macbook I am not sure on how to change that.

Comment: You're not really supposed to put it in any specific 'mode', otherwise it's already making assumptions the i1 then has to fight. Try starting with it at defaults.

Comment: @Tetsujin I calibrated it using the default color space Adobe RGB but then when I use the screen I put it in sRGB

Comment: So… you calibrated it… then changed the screen settings. Back to the drawing board.

Comment: Perhaps my experience was with a different BenQ model. All I know... the polarization on the monitor was exceptionally undesirable. I won't buy another BenQ

Comment: I worked in pre-press at a printer in the 90s. We had the best calibration software, with the best monitors, even hired professional calibrators to do what we struggled with. At the end of the day, all monitors display differently a little or a lot, but the output values were correct. You get the colors exactly right on one monitor, and the next will display differently. It's the nature of the beast. I've never seen anything different.

Answer (score 1):

Just to get this discussion into an answer…

> what could be the culprit here?

Running the colour calibration & then changing the screen's hardware settings.

> How can I find out what monitor is giving me the right colors?

Based on the aforementioned, it's probably the Mac - though only if you don't play with the brightness.